Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBD28B8480 (GameAssembly.dll) when debuging a Unity build deployed onto HoloLens 2
I am deploying a simple build from Unity to HoloLens 2.

I am working with Unity 2021.3.36f1 and VS 2019.
The packages I am using are:

I have been following the HoloLens 2 fundamentals tutorial on this link by Microsoft. Whenever I deploy the build to HoloLens 2 I get the error below:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBD28B8480 (GameAssembly.dll) in MRTK 04.01.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000D26BF03D60).
The error is generated where <<<ERROR>>> is typed on the code block below.
# if defined(ASM_CLEAR_CODE)
    void *GC_clear_stack_inner(void *, ptr_t);
# else
    /* Clear the stack up to about limit.  Return arg.  This function   */
    /* is not static because it could also be erroneously defined in .S */
    /* file, so this error would be caught by the linker.               */
    void *GC_clear_stack_inner(void *arg,
#                           if defined(__APPLE_CC__) && !GC_CLANG_PREREQ(6, 0)
                               volatile /* to workaround some bug */
#                           endif
                               ptr_t limit)
    {  <<<ERROR>>>
#     define CLEAR_SIZE 213 /* granularity */
      volatile word dummy[CLEAR_SIZE];

      BZERO((/* no volatile */ void *)dummy, sizeof(dummy));
      if ((word)GC_approx_sp() COOLER_THAN (word)limit) {
        (void)GC_clear_stack_inner(arg, limit);
      }
      /* Make sure the recursive call is not a tail call, and the bzero */
      /* call is not recognized as dead code.                           */
      GC_noop1((word)dummy);
      return(arg);
    }
# endif /* !ASM_CLEAR_CODE */

The error list that the VS Code generates is 
The lines 1450 to 1510 from misc.c is pasted below:
1450    static GC_bool getWinRTLogPath(wchar_t* buf, size_t bufLen)
1451    {
1452      static const GUID kIID_IApplicationDataStatics = {
1453        0x5612147B, 0xE843, 0x45E3,
1454        0x94, 0xD8, 0x06, 0x16, 0x9E, 0x3C, 0x8E, 0x17
1455      };
1456      static const GUID kIID_IStorageItem = {
1457        0x4207A996, 0xCA2F, 0x42F7,
1458        0xBD, 0xE8, 0x8B, 0x10, 0x45, 0x7A, 0x7F, 0x30
1459      };
1460      GC_bool result = FALSE;
1461      HSTRING_HEADER appDataClassNameHeader;
1462      HSTRING appDataClassName;
1463      __x_ABI_CWindows_CStorage_CIApplicationDataStatics* appDataStatics = 0;
1464
1465      GC_ASSERT(bufLen > 0);
1466      if (SUCCEEDED(WindowsCreateStringReference(
1467                      RuntimeClass_Windows_Storage_ApplicationData,
1468                      (sizeof(RuntimeClass_Windows_Storage_ApplicationData)-1)
1469                        / sizeof(wchar_t),
1470                      &appDataClassNameHeader, &appDataClassName))
1471          && SUCCEEDED(RoGetActivationFactory(appDataClassName,
1472                                              &kIID_IApplicationDataStatics,
1473                                              &appDataStatics))) {
1474        __x_ABI_CWindows_CStorage_CIApplicationData* appData = NULL;
1475        __x_ABI_CWindows_CStorage_CIStorageFolder* tempFolder = NULL;
1476        __x_ABI_CWindows_CStorage_CIStorageItem* tempFolderItem = NULL;
1477        HSTRING tempPath = NULL;
1478
1479        if (SUCCEEDED(appDataStatics->lpVtbl->get_Current(appDataStatics,
1480                                                          &appData))
1481            && SUCCEEDED(appData->lpVtbl->get_TemporaryFolder(appData,
1482                                                              &tempFolder))
1483            && SUCCEEDED(tempFolder->lpVtbl->QueryInterface(tempFolder,
1484                                                        &kIID_IStorageItem,
1485                                                        &tempFolderItem))
1486            && SUCCEEDED(tempFolderItem->lpVtbl->get_Path(tempFolderItem,
1487                                                          &tempPath))) {
1488          UINT32 tempPathLen;
1489          const wchar_t* tempPathBuf =
1490                          WindowsGetStringRawBuffer(tempPath, &tempPathLen);
1490
1491          buf[0] = '\0';
1492          if (wcsncat_s(buf, bufLen, tempPathBuf, tempPathLen) == 0
1493              && wcscat_s(buf, bufLen, L"\\") == 0
1494              && wcscat_s(buf, bufLen, TEXT(GC_LOG_STD_NAME)) == 0)
1495            result = TRUE;
1496          WindowsDeleteString(tempPath);
1497        }
1498
1499        if (tempFolderItem != NULL)
1500          tempFolderItem->lpVtbl->Release(tempFolderItem);
1501        if (tempFolder != NULL)
1502          tempFolder->lpVtbl->Release(tempFolder);
1503        if (appData != NULL)
1504          appData->lpVtbl->Release(appData);
1505        appDataStatics->lpVtbl->Release(appDataStatics);
1506      }
1507      return result;
1508    }
1509 # endif /* MSWINRT_FLAVOR */

I have used ChatGPT but has not got me any where. For the stack overflow error it gave the code below to replace in the misc.c file around line 309.
# if defined(ASM_CLEAR_CODE)
    void *GC_clear_stack_inner(void *, ptr_t);
# else
    /* Clear the stack up to about limit.  Return arg.  This function   */
    /* is now iterative to avoid stack overflow issues.                 */
    void *GC_clear_stack_inner(void *arg,
#                           if defined(__APPLE_CC__) && !GC_CLANG_PREREQ(6, 0)
                               volatile /* to workaround some bug */
#                           endif
                               ptr_t limit)
    {
#     define CLEAR_SIZE 213 /* granularity */
      while ((word)GC_approx_sp() COOLER_THAN (word)limit) {
          volatile word dummy[CLEAR_SIZE];
          BZERO((/* no volatile */ void *)dummy, sizeof(dummy));
          /* Previously recursive call is now simulated by this loop,   */
          /* ensuring we don't overflow the stack with deep recursion.  */
          /* Adjust 'limit' as necessary if the condition needs refining.*/
          /* GC_noop1((word)dummy);  No longer necessary. */
      }
      return(arg);
    }
# endif /* !ASM_CLEAR_CODE */

Before using this suggestion, I was seeing the circling dots on Hololens. But after this change, i can't even open the app from the app menu on HoloLens.
I am a complete newby and trying to learn how use Unity to create interactions and deploy them onto HoloLens which was off to a terrible start.

Hi, how did you install the MRTK3 packages? Did you use the Mixed Reality Feature Tool? I am wondering since you have some MRTK packages under Mixed Reality Toolkit Contributors. Usually all MRTK packages should be under Microsoft

@anjelomerte I side loaded them manually. MRTK Feature Tool was malfunctioning for me. It was crashing and shutting down when was downloading the packages.

Hm, unfortunate. Maybe try again, there should be no reason for it not working. Anyways, sideloading should work as well but possibly sth went wrong for you doing so. Maybe as a reference, try to clone the official MRTK3 Template Project and start your project from here if it works. Still, also for future updates it would be useful if you could get the MRFeatureTool to work
